# How to use rollmean on dplyr grouped data

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, moving-average, rolling-computation

I hope my example data doesn't seem too large

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 
17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 
17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 17532, 
17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 
17836, 17866, 17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 
18109, 18140, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 
17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 
18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 
17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 
17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 17532, 
17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 
17836, 17866, 17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 
18109, 18140, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 
17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 
18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 
17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 
17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 17532, 
17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 
17836, 17866, 17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 
18109, 18140), class = "Date"), Gender = c("Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male"), Age = c("Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", 
"Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", 
"Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", 
"Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", 
"Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", 
"Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", 
"Older", "Older", "Older", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", 
"Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", 
"Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", 
"Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", 
"Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", 
"Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", "Older", 
"Older", "Older", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", "Younger", 
"Younger", "Younger"), attribute = c("Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", "Feeling A", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", "Feeling B", 
"Feeling B"), measure_1 = c(0.33, 0.31, 0.31, 0.16, 0.37, 0.29, 
0.27, 0.26, 0.24, 0.38, 0.47, 0.21, 0.32, 0.24, 0.26, 0.38, 0.38, 
0.39, 0.37, 0.3, 0.29, 0.48, 0.45, 0.45, 0.35, 0.49, 0.44, 0.41, 
0.44, 0.35, 0.38, 0.39, 0.55, 0.45, 0.43, 0.38, 0.38, 0.57, 0.47, 
0.51, 0.48, 0.32, 0.27, 0.22, 0.13, 0.02, 0.12, 0.16, 0.15, 0.17, 
0.23, 0.12, 0.31, 0.12, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.24, 0.06, 0.06, 0.17, 
0.15, 0.14, 0.37, 0.35, 0.2, 0.17, 0.25, 0.2, 0.3, 0.23, 0.26, 
0.14, 0.29, 0.35, 0.14, 0.32, 0.14, 0.14, 0.24, 0.18, 0.24, 0.24, 
0.17, 0.4, 0.3, 0.36, 0.41, 0.38, 0.31, 0.33, 0.43, 0.27, 0.31, 
0.26, 0.29, 0.25, 0.23, 0.38, 0.2, 0.29, 0.26, 0.22, 0.41, 0.25, 
0.45, 0.4, 0.54, 0.51, 0.48, 0.46, 0.4, 0.48, 0.29, 0.33, 0.36, 
0.48, 0.5, 0.32, 0.42, 0.43, 0.35, 0.35, 0.49, 0.44, 0.42, 0.48, 
0.34, 0.44, 0.38, 0.49, 0.27, 0.33, 0.42, 0.31, 0.32, 0.31, 0.38, 
0.46, 0.35, 0.4, 0.36, 0.38, 0.51, 0.41, 0.44, 0.36, 0.7, 0.57, 
0.66, 0.65, 0.57, 0.62, 0.53, 0.52, 0.43, 0.52, 0.53, 0.61, 0.67, 
0.59, 0.57, 0.55, 0.54, 0.67, 0.54, 0.57, 0.57), measure_2 = c(0.5, 
0.47, 0.48, 0.31, 0.54, 0.45, 0.43, 0.42, 0.4, 0.55, 0.66, 0.37, 
0.49, 0.4, 0.42, 0.56, 0.55, 0.57, 0.54, 0.47, 0.45, 0.66, 0.63, 
0.63, 0.52, 0.67, 0.62, 0.58, 0.61, 0.52, 0.55, 0.57, 0.74, 0.63, 
0.61, 0.56, 0.56, 0.77, 0.66, 0.7, 0.67, 0.49, 0.38, 0.32, 0.23, 
0.12, 0.22, 0.26, 0.25, 0.27, 0.34, 0.22, 0.41, 0.21, 0.26, 0.26, 
0.26, 0.34, 0.16, 0.16, 0.27, 0.25, 0.24, 0.48, 0.45, 0.31, 0.27, 
0.36, 0.3, 0.4, 0.34, 0.36, 0.24, 0.39, 0.45, 0.24, 0.43, 0.24, 
0.24, 0.35, 0.28, 0.34, 0.35, 0.27, 0.51, 0.43, 0.48, 0.52, 0.49, 
0.44, 0.46, 0.54, 0.4, 0.44, 0.4, 0.42, 0.39, 0.37, 0.49, 0.34, 
0.42, 0.39, 0.36, 0.52, 0.39, 0.56, 0.51, 0.63, 0.6, 0.58, 0.56, 
0.51, 0.58, 0.42, 0.46, 0.48, 0.58, 0.59, 0.45, 0.52, 0.54, 0.47, 
0.47, 0.58, 0.54, 0.53, 0.7, 0.62, 0.68, 0.64, 0.7, 0.59, 0.62, 
0.67, 0.61, 0.61, 0.61, 0.65, 0.69, 0.63, 0.65, 0.64, 0.64, 0.71, 
0.66, 0.68, 0.63, 0.81, 0.75, 0.8, 0.79, 0.75, 0.77, 0.72, 0.72, 
0.67, 0.72, 0.72, 0.77, 0.8, 0.76, 0.75, 0.73, 0.73, 0.8, 0.73, 
0.75, 0.74)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -168L), na.action = structure(169:176, .Names = c("169", 
"170", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175", "176"), class = "omit"))
```

I'd like to find a tidy type `%>%` solution to rolling grouped data on a 12 month basis. That is, I would like to group multiple categorical variables (such as age and gender and measurement classes) and find the rolling 12 month average for any associated numeric variables

This seems to work but the code is not easy to interpret

```
df1 <- df # mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% select(-date)  %>% group_by(Gender, Age, attribute) %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x, n = 12){stats::filter(x, rep(1 / n, n), sides = 1)})
```

I've read many posts on rollmean and rollmeanr but can't get it working with grouped data. How can I write a one or two line solution using such a straightforward function?

Comment: I formatted the first code block, but I'm not sure why you had the code at the bottom commented out. Any reason? And what about your code doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you camille the code formatting and for your question.  The hashed out code was removing the data variable, while experimenting to get the code to work.  I find it odd in a way that the date variable is not a part of the grouping variable.  The code does seem to work, but I would like to use more tidy verbs and also I believe I've run into difficulties implementing the stats::filter expressions (I will try to capture that here the next time as needed).  I should read more about that tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Using a smaller example (please provide *minimal* data in the future)

```
DF <- data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), value1 = 1:6, value2 = 7:12)

library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

DF %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("value")), list(roll = ~ rollmeanr(., k = 2, fill = NA))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  group value1 value2 value1_roll value2_roll
  <dbl>  <int>  <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1      1      7        NA          NA  
2     1      2      8         1.5         7.5
3     1      3      9         2.5         8.5
4     2      4     10        NA          NA  
5     2      5     11         4.5        10.5
6     2      6     12         5.5        11.5
```

**2)** or if you don't need the original `value1` and `value2`:

```
DF %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("value")), rollmeanr, k = 2, fill = NA) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  group value1 value2
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1   NA     NA  
2     1    1.5    7.5
3     1    2.5    8.5
4     2   NA     NA  
5     2    4.5   10.5
6     2    5.5   11.5
```

**3)** Another approach is

```
DF %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(cbind(., roll = rollmeanr(.[-1], k = 2, fill = NA))) %>%
  ungroup
```

or without the original `value` variables:

```
DF %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(rollmeanr(.[-1], k = 2, fill = NA) %>% as.data.frame) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Can we apply this to multiple associated numeric data, as with my original example, such as   DF <- data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), value1 = 1:6, value2=7:12)?  I would prefer not to have to gather and spread as that also presents more steps for me when holding onto multiple categorical values

Comment: I wrote an outside function to handle this roller <- function(x){
    x <- rollmeanr(x, 2, fill = NA)
      
  }
  
  
  DF %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, roller )

Comment: @Michael Bellhouse, Have revised to use the data in your comment.

Comment: wonderful, thank you for your help.  I have accepted your answer in kind